# Making sure I'm explaining nested GCD correctly

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

So I'm putting 10 tasks on a **concurrent queue** using **dispatch_async**. They do not block the next task, and gets processed in order. My UI is responsive.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    dispatch_async(concurrencyQueue, ^() {

        NSLog(@"..calling insertion method to insert record %d", i);

           dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^() {

            //this is to simulate writing to database
            NSLog(@"----------START %d---------", i);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
            NSLog(@"--------FINISHED %d--------", i);

        });

    });
}
```

Within each task, we simulate a write to database with a "1 sec sleep" on a **serial Queue** via **dispatch_sync**.

I always thought dispatch_sync blocks everyone, and syncs its tasks because that's how it behaves when I use it individually. However, in this situation, it does not block the main thread. Instead, it runs beautifully in the background like I want it.

Is it because whatever thread is associated with the queue is being affected?

For example, the main thread is executing the concurrent queue via dispatch_async and that's why it is not blocked.

The dispatch_sync only syncs and blocks against the background thread that's working on the concurrent queue.  Hence, the dispatch_sync is associated with the background thread, thus never affecting my UI main thread.

Is my thinking correct?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never block the main thread because your code is running on either the threads of the `concurrencyQueue` or the thread of the `serialQueue`. None of those are the main thread.

All of the calls to `sleep` happen one by one on the thread of the `serialQueue`. So it is the thread of the `serialQueue` that is blocked.

However, since you dispatch to the `serialQueue` using `dispatch_sync`, you are also blocking each thread of the concurrent queue. This would be better pictured if you add another `NSLog` after the call to `dispatch_sync`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dispatch_async(concurrencyQueue, ^() {
        NSLog(@"..calling insertion method to insert record %d", i);

        dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^() {
            //this is to simulate writing to database
            NSLog(@"----------START %d---------", i);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
            NSLog(@"--------FINISHED %d--------", i);
        });

        NSLog(@"..called insertion method to insert record %d", i);
    });
}
```

That 2nd `NSLog` after the `dispatch_sync` will show you better how the `dispatch_sync` is affecting the calls to `dispatch_async`.

Comment: @rmaddy - the 2nd log is very helpful. the concurrent queue's thread does not proceed until the dispatch_sync block is finished, then it displays the 2nd nslog.

Comment: @Rob - so wording can be improved to:

"You never block the main thread that's processing the main queue because your code is running..."

"...So it is the background thread that's processing the serialQueue that is blocked..." 

"...since you dispatch to the serialQueue using dispatch_sync, you are also blocking the background thread that's processing the tasks on concurrent queue."

Comment: @Rob and rtsao. I updated my answer to better clarify the use of threads and queues. Does that seem more clear?

Comment: @rmaddy why using a serial queue nested inside a concurrent one and not just the serial? I don't get it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. `dispatch_sync()` blocks only the thread the queue is running on.